# Get children of JSON object python

Tags: json, python-2.7

i am trying to parse some json data in python 2.7, but do not know how to get children elements.

Object structure is like this:

```
{
    "35": {
        "num": 1,
        "name": "Discovery",
        "stream_type": "live",
        "stream_id": "35"
    },
    "13085": {
        "num": 2,
        "name": "Discovery HD",
        "stream_type": "live",
        "stream_id": "13085"
    },
    "36": {
        "num": 3,
        "name": "Discovery Investigation",
        "stream_type": "live",
        "stream_id": "36"
    },
    "151": {
        "num": 4,
        "name": "Discovery Turbo",
        "stream_type": "live",
        "stream_id": "151"
    }

}
```

I load it from url using urllib2 and then use for loop to iterate over it:

```
> import urllib2,json
> 
> data = urllib2.urlopen("http://someurl.eu/json.php") data =
> data.read().decode("utf-8") channels = json.loads(data)
> 
> for channel in channels:
>     print channel   #prints the id's
```

But how i get further ?

If i try:

```
for channel in channels:
    print channel   #prints the id's
    print channel['name']  #trying to get name
```

Then i get:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

I think it wants something like print channel[0] but that just prints me first indice of the id.

I have played around it with other ways also, but i never succeed, anyone can explain a bit please, how this should be done ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For channel in channels iterates through dictionary keys.

You can iterate through values instead of keys:

```
for channel in channels.values():
    print channel   # prints the entire channel
    print channel['name']  # prints name
```

or iterate through keys but access data from dictionary:

```
for channel in channels:
    print channel   # prints the id
    print channels[channel]['name']  # prints name
```